# Illustrator: how to scale strokes proportionally when resizing?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize, stroke

I am working on a logo design project and stuck at a place.
I have used some strokes in logo so problem is, strokes size isn't changing when I am resizing an object.

> Stroke size is 3pt and when I am decreasing size of object with stroke then stroke's size is still 3pt so it is looking bold when decreasing size and thick when increasing size.

What I want is when I resize an object's size, stroke's size must be changed with object. 
 *How can I do this?*

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: @user you can scale stroke with object. No reason to do it manually after.

Comment: @user It is happening now a days but before when I was using strokes and resizing them, their size was changing automatically. I want it work same as before.

Comment: @Ryan you said possible duplicate but I say it is the question I want to ask too. Thanks for letting me know and I have got an answer

Comment: @ryan now what do I do with this question?

Comment: others will vote to close it as a duplicate and it'll be done. Or you can flag it for a moderator to close. Don't worry about it. Hope you'll stick around though and ask other questions too